# How do I make elements fadeOut one by one on click in Jquery and at the end display a message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a game that finishes when you click on the boxes with same colors so that they fadeout on click and at the end display a message.
I am not able to do so, I am relatively new to jquery and javascript. It would be a great help if someone could find a solution.
Here is my script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $(".boxr").click(function() {
        var me = $(this);
        $(".boxr").not(this).fadeTo('slow', 1, function() {
        $(me).next().add(me).fadeOut('slow');
        }).unbind('click');
    $.when($('.boxr').fadeOut(500)).done(function() {
        alert("You WIN!");
    });
        $(".boxy").click(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });
        $(".boxb").click(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });

    });
</script>
```

Here is the html body:

```
<body>
<center>
    <div>
        <h1 style="font-size:72px;">Welcome!</h1>
        <h1 id="op"></h1>
<table><tr>
<td><div class="boxr"  ></div></td>
<td><div class="boxy" ></div></td>
<td><div class="boxb" ></div></td>
<td><div class="boxy" ></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
    </div>
</center>
</body>
```

boxr is a box with red color boxy is yellow and so on.

Comment: Do you mean, when you click on two boxes with the same color, they will fade away?

Comment: No, there can be many boxes,but they have to fade only when clicked

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it as simple as this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    // Bind
    $('#a').click(function () {
        $('#a').fadeOut(500, function () {

            // Remove
            $('#a').remove();

            // Bind again
            $('#b').click(function () {
                $('#b').fadeOut(500, function () {

                    // Remove
                    $('#b').remove();

                    // Bind again!
                    $('#c').click(function () {
                        $('#c').fadeOut(500, function () {

                            // Remove again!
                            $('#c').remove();

                        });
                    });

                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: After removing the `#c` you can alert `"You win!!"`.

Comment: No, the code didn't work  and the boxes are not only 4, there are more boxes, its just that the code couldn't fit. And the script which I gave used to remove all the boxes of same color at once and display the message. Whereas I want it to fade only when clicked.

Comment: @SantoshHegde Trying to put my finger on what you're really asking, sorry if this was wrong. You only want the others to be clickable *once* the others have faded out? If so, you can use my method, and only bind the handles in the callback of the fadeout you want them to be clickable after.

Comment: @Crowes No no. What I want is to fade the ones I click. And once the same color divs have faded out, an alert message gets displayed saying you win. And my code removes all the divs at once.